# Switching a button from default to pressed state and back

Tags: html, css

I made a style for a simple button. This button would open a dropdown menu. As long as the menu is open, the button should have the style of a pressed button.

How can I switch these states? Do I have to use some javascript there? I know I could use `onClick=functionName()`, but how can I turn it back to default?

```css
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}

#menuBtn {
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #3c3e42;
  background: linear-gradient(#5e5f64, #3c3e42);
}

#menuBtnPressed {
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #666666;
  border-color: #3c3e42;
  background: linear-gradient(#2b2d32, #3c3e42);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="menuBtn">Default</button>

<button class="btn" id="menuBtnPressed">Pressed</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't tried using `:active` yet, then I would start with that. But here are two different states that you could use on the button.

> :active : if you want background color only when the button is clicked
>   and don't want to persist.
>
> :focus: if you want background color untill the focus is off the
>   button.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class rather than 2 ids, then simply toggle it on and off on click.

```js
function togglePressed(){
   document.getElementById('menuBtn').classList.toggle('pressed');
}
```

```css
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}

#menuBtn {
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #3c3e42;
  background: linear-gradient(#5e5f64, #3c3e42);
}

#menuBtn.pressed {
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #666666;
  border-color: #3c3e42;
  background: linear-gradient(#2b2d32, #3c3e42);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="menuBtn" onclick="togglePressed()">Default</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but I think :focus is the right thing I was looking for :)